# Function returning a closure not working inside my filter

Tags: rust, closures, trait-objects

I cannot get this to compile without using a closure. I'm trying to get the function `apply` to return the correct kind of closure in the first place.

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]
#![allow(dead_code)]

fn accumulate<'a>(tuples: &[(&'a str, &Fn(i32) -> bool)], i: i32) {

    // this works
    let _ = tuples.iter().filter(|t| apply(second, i)(t));

    // this doesn't
    //let f = apply(second, i);
    //let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);

    //this works as well

    let f  = |t: &&(_,_)| apply(second, i)(t);
    let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);
}

fn apply<A, B, C, F, G>(mut f: F, a: A) -> impl FnMut(B) -> C
         where F: FnMut(B) -> G,
               G: FnMut(A) -> C,
               A: Clone
{
    move |b| f(b)(a.clone())
}


fn second<A, B: ?Sized>(&(_, ref second): &(A, B)) -> &B {
    second
}

fn main()  {}
```

What can I do to make `apply` work like I want it to?

Comment: Based on your feedback to my answer, I suggest you produce an [MCVE] of your problem. Probably [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=67472cbead98bdcdb5ea8cd92925130d).

Comment: I cut it down to just `apply` and `second` - I am trying to solve the HRTBs problem.

Comment: What kind of language doesn't even support such a basic operation as extracting a subexpression, naming it, and being confident it does the same thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, let me say that the problem has nothing to do with the use of the `impl Trait` syntax. I converted the closure to a named struct and got the same results.

So, let's look at the code you'd like to make work:

```
let f = apply(second, i);
let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);
```

What does the compiler have to say about that?

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> impl std::ops::FnMut<(&(_, _),)>: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:11:27
   |
11 |     let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);
   |                           ^^^^^^ trait `for<'r> impl std::ops::FnMut<(&(_, _),)>: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>` not satisfied

error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> impl std::ops::FnMut<(&(_, _),)>: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:11:27
   |
11 |     let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);
   |                           ^^^^^^ trait `for<'r> impl std::ops::FnMut<(&(_, _),)>: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>` not satisfied
```

OK, so we have type X and it needs to implement trait Y but it doesn't. But let's look closely:

```
for<'r> impl
std::ops::FnMut<(&(_, _),)>:
std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(_, _),)>
```

Ah ha! `filter` expects a function that accepts a **reference to a reference** to a tuple, whereas the function we're passing in accepts a reference to a tuple. `filter` passes a reference to a reference because `tuples.iter()` iterates over references, and `filter` passes references to these.

Alright, let's change the definition of `second` to accept references to references:

```
fn second<'a, A, B: ?Sized>(&&(_, ref second): &&'a (A, B)) -> &'a B {
    second
}
```

Compiler still not happy:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> impl std::ops::FnMut<(&&(_, _),)>: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:11:27
   |
11 |     let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);
   |                           ^^^^^^ trait `for<'r> impl std::ops::FnMut<(&&(_, _),)>: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>` not satisfied

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <impl std::ops::FnMut<(&&(_, _),)> as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r &(&str, &std::ops::Fn(i32) -> bool),)>>::Output == bool`
  --> <anon>:11:27
   |
11 |     let _ = tuples.iter().filter(f);
   |                           ^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: concrete lifetime that was found is lifetime '_#24r
```

`expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime`... What does that mean?

`f`'s type is some type that implements `FnMut(&'c &'b (&'a str, &Fn(i32) -> bool)) -> bool`. In the call to `apply`, `B == &'c &'b (&'a str, &Fn(i32) -> bool)` and `C == bool`. Note that `B` is *one fixed type* here; `'c` represents one, fixed lifetime, which is called a *concrete lifetime*.

Let's take a look at `filter`'s signature:

```
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P> where
    Self: Sized, P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

Here, `P` must implement `FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`. Actually, this syntax is shorthand for `for<'r> FnMut(&'r Self::Item) -> bool`. Here. `'r` is a bound lifetime parameter.

So, the problem is that our function that implements `FnMut(&'c &'b (&'a str, &Fn(i32) -> bool)) -> bool` does *not* implement `for<'r> FnMut(&'r Self::Item) -> bool`. We'd need a function that implements `for<'c> FnMut(&'c &'b (&'a str, &Fn(i32) -> bool)) -> bool`. The only way to do this, for now, would be to write `apply` like this:

```
fn apply<A, B, C, F, G>(mut f: F, a: A) -> impl FnMut(&B) -> C
         where F: FnMut(&B) -> G,
               G: FnMut(A) -> C,
               A: Clone
{
    move |b| f(b)(a.clone())
}
```

or the more explicit version:

```
fn apply<A, B, C, F, G>(mut f: F, a: A) -> impl for<'r> FnMut(&'r B) -> C
         where F: for<'r> FnMut(&'r B) -> G,
               G: FnMut(A) -> C,
               A: Clone
{
    move |b| f(b)(a.clone())
}
```

If Rust eventually supports [higher-kinded types](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/higher-kinded-types-the-difference-between-giving-up-and-moving-forward/3908), there *might* be a more elegant way to solve this problem.